# SQL Totals by Date Range

Tags: sql

I am attempting to get my sql query to return the total cost of a reservation, based on if it is available for certain dates, by the unitID

The one table I have has the following columns:

- unitid
- cost
- date
- reservationid (0 if there is no reservation)

I need the return of:

- unitid
- summed cost of two specific days where reservationid = 0

Any help would be much appreciated

Here are a few examples I tried out:

```
SELECT unitid , SUM(rate)
FROM availability
GROUP BY unitid
ORDER BY 2
HAVING reservationid = 0
AND date = 2014-02-21
OR date = 2014-02-22

SELECT unitid , SUM(CASE WHEN 'Date' ='2014-02-21' and 'Date' ='2014-02-22'
         THEN rate
    END) AS weekendrate,
FROM `availability` 
WHERE'Date' BETWEEN '2014-02-21 and 2014-02-22'
AND reservationid = 0
AND NOT reservationrate = 0
GROUP BY unitid
ORDER BY 2 ASC
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `WHERE`.

Comment: I've tried a couple variations of this, but can't seem to get it exactly right

Comment: So post those variations, along with maybe an example of the input data and what you expect. That would help us help you.

Comment: Posted my attempts in the original message as an edit.

The data I'm hoping to achieve is two columns of available reservations and their total 2 day price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exact output you want to get here but to get the unitId and 2 day price you just need to modify your query like this:

```
SELECT unitID, SUM(rate)
FROM availability
WHERE reservationID = 0
AND date1 BETWEEN '2014-02-21' AND '2014-02-22'
GROUP BY unitID
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was really close but couldn't quite seal the deal

Comment: You can read more about SQL in website like this [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/),  [Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/)